# suggest_int or suggest_categorical for binary variables?

Tags: python, optuna

I'm trying to suggest a binary variable in my Optuna trial. I haven't found a direct `trial.suggest_binary`, but I guess I could use both `trial.suggest_int('var', 0, 1)` or `trial.suggest_categorical('var', [True, False])`.

Is there any advantage to use one over the other?